# How to make iOS app communicate with my Parse web server?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform, parse-server

I have a web server where a parse-server-example is running as follows:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/nimbus',
cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'nimbus',
masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'emory',
serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://locahost:5010/parse',
liveQuery: {
classNames: ["Users"]
}
```

Now, I also configured my iOS app the following way (`didFinishLaunching`):

```
Parse.setApplicationId("nimbus", clientKey: "X")
let player = PFObject(className: "User")
player.setObject("Richard", forKey: "Name")
player.setObject("O", forKey: "Password")
player.saveInBackground { (succeeded, error) -> Void in
if succeeded {
            print("Object Uploaded")
        } else {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

However, nothing happens. How do I go about connecting the app and my server together? Also, as Parse has went open source and abandoned their hosting, I can use *any* API key, right?

Comment: Please define "nothing happens"

Answer (score 2):

> How do I go about connecting the app and my server together?

To connect the [Parse iOS SDK](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX) of your app with your [Parse Server](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server),
initialize your Parse SDK with [ParseClientConfiguration](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/ParseClientConfiguration.html)

For example:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Configuration of you parse application
    let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
        $0.applicationId = "MY_APP_ID" // Your App Id
        $0.server = "https://example.com/api" // The URL of your server
    }
    Parse.initialize(with: configuration)

    return true
}
```

> I can use any API key right?

You don't need a client key to connect with your [Parse Server](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server)

I hope my answer was helpful